# Magento: Easy and simple way of (auto)configuring thefind feed and Google Merchant

Tags: magento

How can this be done - smartly ;) ?

What is the best extension out there

- with being somewhat resistant to future changes (i.e. not manually needing to edit a lot of things and setting new attributes)
- Having one method that supports: Google Merchant, thefind, beslist.nl etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use retailtower. Still free.

step 1. Download retailtower plugin

step 2. Goto retailtower website and create acocunt. Wait one week.

step 3. Login and create feeds that read your site (very easy).

step 4. Dont forget to enrich category etc.

step 5. Enter this feed in Google Merchant, TheFind, or in NL Beslist.nl. Easypeasy

Answer (score 0):

TheFind Feed is built into Magento now.  For the rest, there's several services out there that handle feeds for Magento automatically but they're not free.  If you want free then you'll most likely need to integrate the feeds that you want one at a time.  There's a lot of them already completed at http://www.magentoconnect.com/.  A premium service that handles 50+ feed engines from Magento is GoDataFeed: http://www.godatafeed.com

Comment: hmmm pay pay pay. Still having troubles setting up thefind.

Comment: We use retailtower. Still free.